# Java api returning Optional

Tags: java, rest, option-type

I'm communicating with an API, and I have utilised the use of the `Optional` class. But I feel like the error handling could be more elegant, so any suggestions on how to improve this will be well received. Also am I missing a exception handling in the actual api calls?

```
public Optional<Account> getGreenqloudAccount(String accountUUid) {
    System.out.println("tmplog: GreenqloudAccountDao->getGreenqloudAccount");
    for (Account account : apiClient.accountList()) {
        if (account.getUuid().equals(accountUUid)) {
            System.out.println("getGreenqloudAccount, account: " + account.toString());
            return Optional.of(account);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

public Optional<String> getMarketplaceCustomerIdByUsername(String username) {
    if (username == null || username.equals("")) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    AwsMarketplace marketplaceData = apiClient.getMarketplaceData(getKeys(username));
    if (marketplaceData == null) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(marketplaceData.getObjects().get(0).getCustomerId());
}

private Pair getKeys(String username) {
    GetKeys getKeys = apiClient.getKeys(username);
    return new Pair(getKeys.getApiPrivateKey(), getKeys.getApiPublicKey());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean handling corner cases, you could improve the code readability along with them as in the first method using `findFirst` such as:

```
public Optional<Account> getGreenqloudAccount(String accountUUid) {
    System.out.println("tmplog: GreenqloudAccountDao->getGreenqloudAccount");
    return apiClient.accountList().stream()
            .filter(account -> account.getUuId().equals(accountUUid))
            // you can 'peek' and log 
            .findFirst(); // you return the first account or empty 
}
```

Moving further with the other API, notice `Optional.map` handles operations returning `null` values and returns `Optional.empty` for them implicitly. So you can use:

```
public Optional<String> getMarketplaceCustomerIdByUsername(String username) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(username) // if username is null empty
            .filter(name -> !name.isEmpty()) // empty string returns filtered out
            .map(name -> apiClient.getMarketplaceData(getKeys(name))) // handles 'null' calue returned
            .map(marketplaceData -> marketplaceData.getObjects().get(0).getCustomerId()); // here as well
}
```

Comment: Like your approach, specially for the latter function, don't think the former adds any performance or readability.

Comment: @JonB The former is a simplified version of the iteration using the [tag:java-stream] API. Its a matter of opinion, for me it does read better. (find the first such account or else return absence)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code: you throw plenty of *very different* outcomes into the same "bucket".

`getMarketplaceCustomerIdByUsername()` for example returns an empty Optional when:

- the username is null
- the username is "" (and think about it `""` means empty, but `" "` isnt empty?!)
- no `AwsMarketplace` instance can be found for the given user

As said, these are **very** different problems. The first one might indicate: the provided user name is bad, so you should tell your user about that. The last one means: "something is fishy, maybe the user is unknown, or something else happened".

Thus: consider to not reduce different results into an empty Optional. Rather consider to throw (different?) exceptions. You use Optional when "no result" is a *valid* result of the operation. But "no result, because bad user name" doesn't feel like a valid result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check using `Optional.isPresent()`

or

use `Optional.orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier)`

Read JDK8 Doc about Optional [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Additionally, you might want to trim your input parameters before checking for empty strings